# Limit class of ugly sequence with integral

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$\renewcommand{\d}[1]{\operatorname{d}\!{#1}}$

I am to take Analysis 4 in a few days and running through old exam exercises I found this gem:

> Determine the limit class of the following sequence:
>
> $$\left \{ (-n)^{n+1} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1-\cos \sqrt{x/n}}{(n+x^2)^n}\d x \right \}_{n=1}^\infty $$
>   *(It may be useful to know that, for any fixed t, the sequence $\{(1+t/n)^n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is increasing.*

And here is what I've been able to do:

First of all, the sequence is clearly alternating, since everything in there is positive except for that $(-n)^{n+1}$ term. So I just looked at the positive half, expecting the negative to do the same, but mirrored around $0$.

Then I split the generic term of the sequence in two:

(let $f$ be the argument of the integral)

$$ (-n)^{n+1} \int_0^{+\infty} f(x)\d x =\\ 
= (-n)^{n+1} \left( 
\int_0^1 f(x)\d x + 
\int_1^{+\infty} f(x)\d x
\right)$$

Now, the first part is easily controlled:

For $z \to 0$,

$$ \cos(z)\geq 1-\frac12z^2 $$

and therefore,

$$ \int_0^1 f(x)\d x \leq \int_0^1 \frac{\frac12 \frac xn}{n^n (1+x^2/n)^n} \d x $$

And since, as per the hint, $(1+x^2/n)^n$ is increasing,

$$n^{n+1} \int_0^1 \frac{1-\cos \sqrt{x/n}}{(n+x^2)^n}\d x \leq \\
\leq n^{n+1} \int_0^1 \frac{x}{2n^{n+1}(1+x^2/n)^n}\d x = \\
= \frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{x}{(1+x^2/n)^n}\d x \leq \\
\leq \frac12 \int_0^1 \frac x{1+x^2} \d x = \frac 14 \log(2)$$

I also thought I had a good lower bound, but in typing I found out it was nonsense.

As for the second half, I have been extremely successful at showing that its absolute value is greater than zero and smaller than infinity.

Since I do not give up easily, I have written a quick-and-dirty [matlab script](http://pastebin.com/su86nQKs) to try and get a feel at what this damn thing does, and here's the result:

[image]

... Well, at least it is symmetrical.
It also appears to go to to $1/2$, which means that the second part should oscillate by about $0.2$...

Anybody willing to help? Please?

Comment: Your terminology is unfamiliar to me.  I can tell that by "succession" you mean what is usually called a sequence.  But what do you mean by "limit class"? I am guessing that by  "limit class" you mean answers of the type  "$a_n$ has a finite positive lim inf but lim sup goes to infinity",  but is that what you mean?

Comment: @MarkFischler Yes, I meant sequence. Also, $l$ is an element of the limit class for $a_n$ if a subsequence exists such that $a_k \to l$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer will turn out to be the limit class $\{-\frac14, \frac14\}$.  Here is how to show that if 
$$ a_n = (-n)^{n+1} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1-\cos \sqrt{x/n}}{(n+x^2)^n}\d x  
$$
then for all $n>1$, $|a_n| \leq \frac14 \frac{n}{n-1}$:

As you pointed out, for $x>0$,
$$ \cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{n}} \right) \geq 1-\frac{x}{2n} \implies 
1-\cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{n}} \right) \leq \frac{x}{2n}
$$
So
$$|a_n| \leq n^n\int_0^\infty n \frac{x}{2n} (n+x^2)^{-n} dx = 
n^n\left[ \frac{(n+x^2)^{-n+1}}{-n+1} \frac{1}{2n}\frac12 \right]_0^\infty
$$
The $x=\infty$ end is zero (since $n>1$ the $(x^2)^{-n+1}$ becomes smaller than $\frac{1}{n^n}$ for sufficiently large $x$).  The zero end then gives
$$
|a_n| \leq -n^n\frac14 n^{-n}\frac{n}{-n+1} =   \frac14 \frac{n}{n-1}
$$

In a similar way, you can show that $|a_n| \geq \frac14$ and that implies that the limit will be $\frac14$.

Comment: Oh well, now you make it look easy. I didn't even think of integrating there. I edited the picture to make it look as it should.